# How to use transactions in Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I want to use Datastore from Cloud Compute through Java and I am following [Getting started with Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/).

My use case is quite standard - read one entity (lookup), modify it and save the new version. I want to do it in a transaction so that if two processes do this, the second one won't overwrite the changes made by the first one.

I managed to issue a transaction and it works. However I don't know what would happen if the transaction fails:

- How to identify a failed transaction? Probably a DatastoreException with some specific code or name will be thrown?
- Should I issue a rollback explicitly? Can I assume that if a transaction fails, nothing from it will be written?
- Should I retry?
- Is there any documentation on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to identify a failed transaction? Probably a DatastoreException
>   with some specific code or name will be thrown?

Your code should always ensure that a transaction is either successfully committed or rolled back. Here's an example:

```java
// Begin the transaction.
BeginTransactionRequest begin = BeginTransactionRequest.newBuilder()
    .build();
ByteString txn = datastore.beginTransaction(begin)
  .getTransaction();
try {
  // Zero or more transactional lookup()s or runQuerys().
  // ...

  // Followed by a commit().
  CommitRequest commit = CommitRequest.newBuilder()
      .setTransaction(txn)
      .addMutation(...)
      .build();
  datastore.commit(commit);
} catch (Exception e) {
  // If a transactional operation fails for any reason,
  // attempt to roll back. 
  RollbackRequest rollback = RollbackRequest.newBuilder()
      .setTransaction(txn);
      .build();
  try {
    datastore.rollback(rollback);
  } catch (DatastoreException de) {
    // Rollback may fail due to a transient error or if
    // the transaction was already committed.
  }
  // Propagate original exception.
  throw e;
}
```

An exception might be thrown by `commit()` or by another `lookup()` or `runQuery()` call inside the `try` block. In each case, it's important to clean up the transaction.

> Should I issue a rollback explicitly? Can I assume that if a
>   transaction fails, nothing from it will be written?

Unless you're sure that the `commit()` succeeded, you should explicitly issue a `rollback()` request. However, a failed `commit()` does not necessarily mean that no data was written. See the note on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions).

> Should I retry?

You can retry using exponential backoff. However, frequent transaction failures may indicate that you are attempting to write too frequently to an [entity group](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

> Is there any documentation on that?

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions