# Cloud Datastore transaction terminated without explicit rollback defined

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

From following document: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions

1. What would happen if transaction fails with no explicit rollback defined? For example, if we're performing `put()` operation on value arguments.
2. The document states that transaction should be idempotent, what does this mean with respect to `put()` operation? It is not clear how idempotency is applied in this context.
3. How do we detect failure if failure from commit is not reliable according to the documentation?
4. We are seeing some symptoms where `put()` against value argument is sometimes partially saving the data. Note we do not have explicit rollback defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may already know, Datastore transactions are guaranteed to be *[atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems))*, which means that it applies the *all-or-nothing* principle; either all operations succeed or they all fail. This ensures that the data in your database remains consistent over time.

Now, regardless whether you execute *put* or any other operation in your transaction, your implementation of the code should always ensure that your transaction has either successfully commited or rolled back. This means that if you aren't fully sure whether the *commit* succeeded, you should explicitly issue a *rollback*.

However, there may be some exceptions where a *commit* might fail, and this doesn't necessarily mean that no data was written to your database. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions) even points out that *"you can receive errors in cases where transactions have been committed*."

The simple way to detect transaction failures would be to add a try/catch block in your code for when an *Exception* (failed transactional operation) or *DatastoreException* (errors related to Datastore - failed commit) are thrown. I believe that you may already have an answer in this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139861/how-to-use-transactions-in-cloud-datastore) about this particular question.

A good practice is to make your transactions [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) whenever possible. In other words, if you're executing a transaction that includes a write operation *put()* to your database, if this operation were to fail and needed to be retried, the end result should ideally remain the same.

A real world example can be - you're trying to transfer some money to your friend; the transaction consists of withdrawing 20 USD from your bank account and depositing this same amount into your friend's bank account. If the transaction were to fail and had to be retried, the transaction should still operate with the same amount of money (20 USD) as the final result.

Keep in mind that the Datastore API doesn't retry transactions by default, but you can add your own retry logic to your code, as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#uses_for_transactions).

In summary, if a transaction is interrupted and your logic doesn't handle the failure accordingly, you may eventually see inconsistencies in the data of your database.